# Axioms for (pre-) (quasi-) abelian categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

In abelian categories for a morphism $u:X\to Y$ the cannonical morphism $\bar{u}:\mathrm{Coim}(u)→\mathrm{Im}(u)$ is an isomorphism. However this is a property, not a part of the axioms of abelian categories. There are different weaker types of categories (pre-, semi- and quasi-abelian) that allow this situation (I believe, initially quasi-abelian categories were called semi-abelian, f.e. in papers of Raikov, and now this term is used differently, but I am not sure by now).

My question is - is there a unified system of axioms for those categories? So that one could say that, for example, Preabelian+(Axiom A)=quasi-abelian, quasi-abelian+(Axiom B)=abelian, etc.

Comment: Just for others reading: regarding the terminology, I think that quasi-abelian is the terminology used by Schneiders and some others for what Raikov called semi-abelian, see page 166 of http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CTGDC_2004__45_3_162_0

Comment: For reference: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-abelian+category - this is the modern usage.